# How delete arrays with numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to delete the arrays of this matrix:

https://mega.co.nz/#!wNo2Cb5T!0EoALVMtTJbC1-7dgFLbVK8deinL8tGK0eI68bRCOwo

I need delete only the arrays that have -1 in the last column, I tried this but doesn't work:

```
for i in range (m):
     if matriz[i][8]==-1:
     matriz=numpy.delete(matriz,i,0)
```

Any idea? :)

Comment: What do you mean: `'It doesn't work?'`. Does it do nothing? Does it crash? Does it produce an adverse result?

Comment: The problem is that the output still have arrays with "-1" in the last column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually shouldn't "delete" here, you should just use indexing:

```
good_rows = matriz[:,8] != -1
good_matriz = matrix[good_rows]
```

This will give you the rows where the 9th column is not `-1`, and it's more efficient than deleting one column at a time because it doesn't copy your data.